# Awk - Regular expression matching against substrings

Tags: regex, string, awk

How can I check if the first char with `substr($x, 0, 1)` is a letter from A to L?

Comment: Why use substr() instead of just `$x ~ /^[A-L]/`?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I posted this question ;)

Comment: Then re-phrase your question to tell us what it is you're trying to do with some small set of representative sample input and expected output. So far you've asked us how to implement a specific solution to a problem but you haven't told us what the problem is or asked for a good solution to that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first in

```
substr($x, 0, 1)
```

you better use

```
substr($x, 1, 1)
```

because awk array, string idx etc are all 1-based. gawk works both `0` and `1` (even `-100)` , other awk implementation may not work for `0` case (gives you unexpected value).

you could check that letter range with regex, or just compare them with `> or <`, for example:

```
awk 'BEGIN{s=substr($x,1,1);print (s>="A"&&s<="L")?"YES":"NO"}'
```

if you want to check it with regex, you don't need the `substr()` function:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print ($x~/^[A-L]/)?"YES":"NO"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the regular expression match operator `~` like so `substr($x,0,1)~/[A-L]/`.

```
$ cat file
ABC
DEF
XYZ
123

$ awk 'substr($0,0,1)~/[A-L]/' file
ABC
DEF
```